# can't insert data into mysql

Tags: java, mysql

i have a problem with my project
here is my pTwitterEx.java

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * @author tasgnab
 * how to use:
 * 1. copy-paste folder tempat menyimpan hasil crawl per topik pada variabel dir
 * 2. masukkan topik sabagai label di databae pada variabel topik
 * 3. run file
 */
public class pTwitterEx {
    private static Database db = new Database();
    private static String dir = "D:\\KULIAH\\semester7\\TA2\\java\\dataset\\baik";
    private static String topik = "baik";
    private static int count=0;
    public static void main(String[]args){
        db.query("truncate twitter");
        String temp="a";
        while (!"iniadalahpenanda".equals(temp)){
            FileRead fr = new FileRead(dir+count);
            try {
                JSONObject J = new JSONObject(fr.getTeks());
                String C = J.get("text");
                db.query("insert into twitter values '"+C+"','"+topik+"'");
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                temp = "iniadalahpenanda";
                //System.exit(0);
                //Logger.getLogger(pTwitterEx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            count++;
        }
        //db.query("insert into twitterfix select distinct comment,'"+topik+"' from twitter");
    }
}
```

my problem is,the data from folder "baik" to my database in mysql. name of field in my database is text(type : text) and topik(type : varchar).

when i run the program, it show no error but the data in my database still empty.
can you help me to solve my problem?any help will appreciate...
thanks anyway....

Comment: What is your `Database` type, and does it have the same inappropriate exception handling as the code you've shown?

Comment: are you getting some error?

Comment: the database contain rows name text(type : varchar) and topik(type : varchar)...and i don't know the error because when i run it,it show no error but the data isn't enter to my database.....why is that?

Comment: note that you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0):

To finish an expression in a DB(at least in MySQL), add a ";" at the end of a line.

Sorry, change this line:

```
db.query("insert into twitter values '"+C+"','"+topik+"'");
```

to this line:

```
db.query("insert into twitter values '"+C+"','"+topik+"';");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get what you mean. Is that the Exception Nambari was asking for, or are you telling me that the Variable `C` is a String? Also.. Did you try the same commands in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like: Observer the brace `(` and `)`

Example:

```
db.query("insert into twitter values( '"+C+"','"+topik+"')");
```

Comment: @AdamAzhary: There will be some exception if it is not working, print stack trace in your exception block instead of simply assigning value there. exception stack will give some clues.